# Spring websocket is automatically closed after 30 minutes (timeout)

Tags: java, spring-boot, websocket

I'm trying to implement a websocket on using Spring Boot (1.5.13).

The messaging works fine but after about 30 minutes the connection is terminated by the server (Reason 1008 - "This connection was established under an authenticated HTTP session that has ended"). I've tried to set different timeouts but doesn't seem to have any effect.

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class OCPPSocketHandler extends TextWebSocketHandler {
    @Override
    public void handleTextMessage(WebSocketSession webSocketSession, TextMessage textMessage)
        throws IOException {
      ...
    }
}

@Configuration
@EnableWebSocket
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketConfigurer {

    public static final String ENDPOINT = "/pp/v2.0";

    @Autowired
    private CustomSocketHandler socketHandler;

    public void registerWebSocketHandlers(WebSocketHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addHandler(
            new CustomExceptionWebSocketHandlerDecorator(socketHandler), ENDPOINT
        )
        .setAllowedOrigins("*");
    }
}
```

application.properties:

```
#6h as milliseconds
server.connection-timeout=3600000 
server.servlet.session.timeout=6h
```

A TextMessage (WebSocket) is sent every 30 minutes to keep the connection alive.

I've seen [this question about session timeouts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25930285/spring-websocket-timeout-settings) but I can't see a solution there

Comment: Reason 1008 being "POLICY_VIOLATION
"1008 indicates that an endpoint is terminating the connection because it has received a message that violates its policy"? Have you checked your logs for if there is a policy violating message being sent?

Answer (score 4):

I found my WebSocket closed after 30 minutes too.

The root reason is the http session will close after 30 minutes by default in SpringBoot.

In SpringBoot config property `server.servlet.session.timeout` will change the default behavior, but there might have [some limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54193797/server-servlet-session-timeout-is-not-working-in-spring-boot-project-in-digitalo).

Besides, WebSocket connections have pingpong messages to keep alive, so the connection should never be closed, until the pingpong stops.

After some tracing, I found a way to solve this problem:

1. The timer to close the connection is here `io.undertow.server.session.InMemorySessionManager.SessionImpl` in my case.
2. As we can see `io.undertow.server.session.InMemorySessionManager.SessionImpl#setMaxInactiveInterval` will reset the timer.
3. This method will be called by `javax.servlet.http.HttpSession#setMaxInactiveInterval`.
4. So, once `setMaxInactiveInterval` is called before each timeout, the connection will never be closed.

Here is my implementation:

1. Store the `HandshakeRequest` into the `javax.websocket.EndpointConfig#getUserProperties` in the Configurator `javax.websocket.server.ServerEndpointConfig.Configurator#modifyHandshake`
2. **Our clients will send String messages to keep alive,** so in the `onMessage` method, fetch the `HandshakeRequest` from `javax.websocket.Session#getUserProperties`, then

```java
HttpSession httpSession = (HttpSession) handshakeRequest.getHttpSession();
httpSession.setMaxInactiveInterval((int) (session.getMaxIdleTimeout() / 1000));
```

That's all, hope it helps.

Comment: *setMaxInactiveInterval will reset the timer* does not work for me, but just switching to a 3h session is ok, since my client will auto connect when server brings down the session

Comment: Could you show us the detail implementation ?

Answer (score 1):

From the [Docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web.html#websocket) in *4.2.4. Server Configuration* is the following, hope it can help you:

> Each underlying WebSocket engine exposes configuration properties that control runtime characteristics, such as the size of message buffer sizes, idle timeout, and others.

For Tomcat, WildFly, and GlassFish, you can add a ServletServerContainerFactoryBean to your WebSocket Java config, as the following example shows:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocket
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketConfigurer {

    @Bean
    public ServletServerContainerFactoryBean createWebSocketContainer() {

        ServletServerContainerFactoryBean container = new ServletServerContainerFactoryBean();
        container.setMaxSessionIdleTimeout(120000L); // set the timeout to 2min

        // ...
        return container;
    }

}
```

For Jetty, you need to supply a pre-configured Jetty WebSocketServerFactory and plug that into Spring’s DefaultHandshakeHandler through your WebSocket Java config. The following example shows how to do so:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocket
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void registerWebSocketHandlers(WebSocketHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addHandler(echoWebSocketHandler(),
            "/echo").setHandshakeHandler(handshakeHandler());
    }

    @Bean
    public DefaultHandshakeHandler handshakeHandler() {

        WebSocketPolicy policy = new WebSocketPolicy(WebSocketBehavior.SERVER);
        policy.setInputBufferSize(8192);
        policy.setIdleTimeout(600000); // set the timeout to 10min

        return new DefaultHandshakeHandler(
                new JettyRequestUpgradeStrategy(new WebSocketServerFactory(policy)));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The connection can be closed if any between server or client closes it, and also by a firewall if it notes that there is no activity on the established connection.

So you need to check timeout also on the client side. It is reasanable that 30 minutes is the default timeout for this kind of connection so it seams that on the client side it uses default values.

Additionally it is a good design to check periodically  the status of the connection, for example sending a sort of ping (message from the client) /pong (response from the server) message. If you do it every minute for example you have an idea of the connection status and the connection will never be closed for inactivity.

Comment: I've send a TextMessage for testing today every 2 minutes. The result stays the same. The connection is closed after ~30 minutes.

Comment: Very strange... And it closes the connection with what message?

Comment: Connection closed: /127.0.0.1:58859 Close Status: 1008 Reason: This connection was established under an authenticated HTTP session that has ended.

Comment: @Sebastian did you get any solution to resolve this issue? I'm facing the same issue. sending msg every 30s from the server to the client.

Answer (score 0):

1. In my case, timeout of HttpSession in SpringBoot is set to
   `server.servlet.session.timeout: 1` (1 minute)
2. Set websocket endpoint in Spring Security config to httpBasic

   ```
   @Override
   protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
       http.csrf().disable();
       http.antMatcher("/ocpp/**")
       .authorizeRequests()                         
       .anyRequest().permitAll()//.hasAnyRole("CS","SYSTEM_ADMIN")
       .and().httpBasic();
   }
   ```
3. use basic authentication in websocket client

   ```
       String id = "testuser";
       String pw = "1234";
       String idpw = new String(Base64.getEncoder().encode((id+":"+pw).getBytes()));

       System.out.println("id["+id+"]pw["+pw+"]idpw["+idpw+"]");
       ;
       Map<String, String> httpHeaders = new HashMap<String, String>();
       httpHeaders.put("authorization", "Basic "+idpw);
       WebSocketClient webSocketClient = new WebSocketClient(new URI("ws://localhost:9112/ocpp/testuser")
               , new Draft_6455(Collections.emptyList(), Collections.singletonList(new Protocol("ocpp2.0.1")))
               , httpHeaders
       ) {
       ...
   ```

In this condition, if the endpoint is a protected resource, websocket close 1008 occurs when the HttpSession is terminated.

[Reference](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/websocket/2.0/websocket-spec-2.0.pdf): Read Paragraph 7.2

**The solution is to directly implement http basic processing in websocket addInterceptor.
(Spring Security httpBasic not use)
**

add `addInterceptor` in `WebSocketConfig.java`:

```
.addInterceptors(new HandshakeInterceptor() {
    @Override
    public boolean beforeHandshake(ServerHttpRequest serverHttpRequest, ServerHttpResponse serverHttpResponse, WebSocketHandler wsHandler, Map<String, Object> attributes) throws Exception {
        log.debug("===============================================================");
        log.debug("beforeHandshake[]"+attributes);
        ServletServerHttpRequest ssreq = (ServletServerHttpRequest)serverHttpRequest;
        ServletServerHttpResponse ssres = (ServletServerHttpResponse)serverHttpResponse;
        HttpServletRequest req = ssreq.getServletRequest();
        HttpServletResponse res = ssres.getServletResponse();
        HttpSession session = req.getSession();
        log.debug("session["+session.getId());
        log.debug("session["+session.getMaxInactiveInterval());

        //authentication
        try {
            String header = req.getHeader("Authorization");
            log.debug("header[" + header + "]");
            if (header == null) {
                log.debug("The Authorization header is empty");
//                                    throw new BadCredentialsException("The Authorization header is empty");
            } else {
                header = header.trim();
                if (!StringUtils.startsWithIgnoreCase(header, "Basic")) {
                    log.debug("The Authorization header does not start with Basic.");
                } else if (header.equalsIgnoreCase("Basic")) {
                    throw new BadCredentialsException("Empty basic authentication token");
                } else {
                    byte[] base64Token = header.substring(6).getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
                    byte[] decoded;
                    try {
                        decoded = Base64.getDecoder().decode(base64Token);
                    } catch (IllegalArgumentException var8) {
                        throw new BadCredentialsException("Failed to decode basic authentication token");
                    }
                    String token = new String(decoded, "UTF-8");
                    int delim = token.indexOf(":");
                    if (delim == -1) {
                        throw new BadCredentialsException("Invalid basic authentication token");
                    } else {
                        log.info("TOKEN [" +token+"]");
                        String principal = token.substring(0, delim);
                        String credencial = token.substring(delim + 1);
                        //your 
                        
                        if(principal.equals("testuser") && credencial.equals("1234")){
                            log.debug("login OK");
                        }else{
                            throw new BadCredentialsException("Invalid basic authentication token");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            log.error("Basic Authentication error", e);

            res.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
            res.addHeader("WWW-Authenticate", "Basic realm=" + "Realm" + "");
            PrintWriter pw = res.getWriter();
            pw.println("Invalid status code received: 401 Status line: HTTP/1.1 401");
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
```