# Application property "server.servlet.session.timeout" is not working in Spring Boot project

Tags: java, spring, session, tomcat, server

According to the documentation of Spring Boot, session timeout can be configured by setting

```
server.servlet.session.timeout= 300s
```

in `application.properties` file. In [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40974955/spring-boot-java-config-set-session-timeout) and in [Spring Boot documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.4.x/reference/html/common-application-properties.html) it is also said so. But unfortunately this is not working for me.

Is there any other configuration to get expected result?

Comment: The `server.*` properties will only work if you use the embedded container. If you are deploying to Tomcat those won't work as Spring Boot isn't controlling the container.

Comment: @M.Deinum, Can you give me any suggestion about, how can I set session timeout in my project which is currently running on server ?

Comment: By including a `web.xml` or `web-fragment.xml` and set the session timeout in that way just as you regularly would do.

Comment: @M.Deinum, Can you please give me any reference ?

Comment: A reference to what? Just check how you would set the session timeout in a regular web application. That applies here as well.

Comment: @M.Deinum, Where I will have to put `web.xml` in spring boot project ? In resource folder ?

Comment: No as stated in the normal location the `WEB-INF` folder. It is a regular WAR you are deploying, there is no magic in there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am posting answer because this scenario is new for me. And I haven't got proper solution step by step. 
According to the suggestion of `M. Deinum` I created a `web.xml` file under `WEB-INF` folder. Project structure is like

```
src
 |_ main
     |_ java
     |_ resources
     |_ webapp
         |_ WEB-INF
              |_ web.xml
```

And in `web.xml` I configured  `<session-timeout>...</session-timeout>`

My `web.xml` is like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
         id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">


    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>5</session-timeout>
    </session-config>

</web-app>
```

And now session time of my webapp in server is working according to my configuration. Thanks goes to `M. Deinum`

Answer (score 10):

You can use 
Approach 1:

```
server.servlet.session.timeout=30s
server.servlet.session.cookie.max-age=30s
```

It is working fine for me

Comment: In my case just the cookie max age property was enough.

Answer (score 8):

A possible cause for this problem might be using `@EnableRedisHttpSession`. As explained in this [answer](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/15757#issuecomment-456427179):

> By using @EnableRedisHttpSession you are telling Spring Boot that you want to take complete control over the configuration of Redis-based HTTP sessions. As a result, its auto-configuration backs off and server.servlet.session.timeout has no effect. If you want to use server.servlet.session.timeout then you should remove @EnableRedisHttpSession. Alternatively, if you want to use @EnableRedisHttpSession then you should use the maxInactiveIntervalInSeconds attribute to configure the session timeout.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 4):

`server.servlet.session.timeout` only works for spring boot embedded container.

If you want to deploy the application to an external container, implement `HttpSessionListener` and `ServletRequestListener`.

```
@Component
public class MyHttpSessionListener implements HttpSessionListener {
    @Value("${server.servlet.session.timeout}")
    Duration sessionTimout;

    @Override
    public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent event) {
        event.getSession().setMaxInactiveInterval((int) sessionTimout.getSeconds());
    }
}

@Component
public class MyServletRequestListener implements ServletRequestListener {
    @Value("${server.servlet.session.timeout}")
    Duration sessionTimout;
    
    @Override
    public  void requestInitialized(ServletRequestEvent sre) {
        HttpSession sh = ((HttpServletRequest) sre.getServletRequest()).getSession(false);

        if (sh != null) {
            long t = sh.getCreationTime();
            long duration = (System.currentTimeMillis() - t) / 1000;

            if (duration > sessionTimout.getSeconds()) {
                sh.invalidate();
            }
        }
    }
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Follow the below solution.

1. Set the session time out in `application.properties` file like below.

   ```
   server.servlet.session.timeout=01m
   ```
2. Specify the invalid session URL in `WebSecurityConfiguration` file like below

   ```
   http.sessionManagement().invalidSessionUrl("/sessionexpired");
   ```
3. Configure the session expired mapping in `controller` class like below

   ```
   @RequestMapping(value = "/sessionexpired", method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public ModelAndView sessionexpired(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) {

            return new ModelAndView("sessionexpired");

   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, my app runs on Tomcat server, application.properties set did not work.
This one works:

```
        @Component
        public class SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler {
        @Override
            public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) throws ServletException, IOException {
        
                SavedRequest savedRequest = requestCache.getRequest(request, response);
                String userRole = authentication.getAuthorities().stream().findFirst().get().getAuthority();
//see here timeout duration set
                request.getSession().setMaxInactiveInterval(3600);
        
                List<String> permissions = new ArrayList<>();
    ...
    }
```

and set it to security configure method's

> .successHandler()

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler successHandler;

@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/rest/api/**", "/logout")
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .cors()
                .configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource())
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .failureHandler(new SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler())
                .successHandler(successHandler)
                .and()
                .logout()
                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout", HttpMethod.POST.toString()))
                .clearAuthentication(true)
                .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                .logoutSuccessHandler(new HttpStatusReturningLogoutSuccessHandler())
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(restAuthenticationEntryPoint)
                .and()
                .csrf()
                .disable();
    }
```