# Spring Boot Session Timeout for Standalone Tomcat

Tags: spring, spring-boot, session

i have configured property `server.session.timeout` for my application's timeout and this is working fine for embedded tomcat. But when i deploy my application to standalone tomcat, it doesn't read this property. It applies default timeout of 30 mins. I want to change this.

I tried to put web.xml with just timeout property, but looks like web.xml was not read.

Comment: Any solution for this, am having same problem...

Comment: Unfortunately, these configuration properties don't work for standalone tomcat. This SO answer may help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57072516/4090386