# How to set spring security session timeout?

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-security

I'm using spring security in a tomcat server. How can I change the default session timeout ?

I've tried modifying the web.xml with:

```
<session-config>
         <session-timeout>1</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

This does not seem to work.

I also read that spring boot uses the parameter server.servlet.session.timeout, but I don't use spring boot.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54195305/6622913

Comment: This is what I've tried, as said in my question. But it does not seem to work. More specifically, I still see in the logs `firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'`and then `Obtained a valid SecurityContext from SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT`, even though 1 minute as expired.

Comment: Timeout is 1 minute-ish. Tomcat has a reaper thread to kill timedout sessions, however that runs about every minute. So it can take more then a minute actually to clean the sessions.

Comment: I waited far more than a minute (say, 10 minutes), and nothing happens... Are you sure that the configuration I wrote is supposed to force the user to reauthenticate after 1 minute?

Answer (score 1):

Different ways to configure session timeout time(maxInactiveInterval) in spring security.

> 1. By addinng session config in web.xml
> 2. By creating implementation of HttpSessionListener and adding it to servlet context.(from munilvc's answer)
> 3. By registering your custom AuthenticationSuccessHandler in spring security configuration, and setting session maximum inactive interval
>    in onAuthenticationSuccess method.

This implementation has advantages

- On login success, You can set different value of maxInactiveInterval for different roles/users.
- On login success, you can set user object in session, hence user object can be accessed in any controller from session.

Disadvantage: You can not set session timeout for ANONYMOUS user(Un-authenticated user)

- Create AuthenticationSuccessHandler Handler

  ```
   public class MyAuthenticationSuccessHandler implements AuthenticationSuccessHandler{

   public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication)
           throws IOException 
   {
       Set<String> roles = AuthorityUtils.authorityListToSet(authentication.getAuthorities());
       if (roles.contains("ROLE_ADMIN"))
       {
           request.getSession(false).setMaxInactiveInterval(60);
       }
       else
       {
           request.getSession(false).setMaxInactiveInterval(120);
       }
       //Your login success url goes here, currently login success url="/"
       response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath());
   }
   }
  ```

Register success handler

In Java Config way

```
@Override
protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
{
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/resources/**", "/login").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/app/admin/*").hasRole("ADMIN")
            .antMatchers("/app/user/*", "/").hasAnyRole("ADMIN", "USER")
        .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/403")
        .and().formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login").usernameParameter("userName")
            .passwordParameter("password")
            .successHandler(new MyAuthenticationSuccessHandler())
            .failureUrl("/login?error=true")
        .and().logout()
            .logoutSuccessHandler(new CustomLogoutSuccessHandler())
            .invalidateHttpSession(true)
        .and().csrf().disable();

    http.sessionManagement().maximumSessions(1).expiredUrl("/login?expired=true");
}
```

In xml config way

```
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true" create-session="ifRequired">
    <csrf disabled="true"/>

    <intercept-url pattern="/resources/**" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/login" access="permitAll" />

    <intercept-url pattern="/app/admin/*" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_USER', 'ROLE_ADMIN')" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/app/user/*" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_USER', 'ROLE_ADMIN')" />

    <access-denied-handler error-page="/403" />

    <form-login 
        login-page="/login"
        authentication-success-handler-ref="authenticationSuccessHandler"
        authentication-failure-url="/login?error=true" 
        username-parameter="userName"
        password-parameter="password" />

    <logout invalidate-session="false" success-handler-ref="customLogoutSuccessHandler"/>

    <session-management invalid-session-url="/login?expired=true">
        <concurrency-control max-sessions="1" />
    </session-management>
 </http>

 <beans:bean id="authenticationSuccessHandler" class="com.pvn.mvctiles.configuration.MyAuthenticationSuccessHandler" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm not sure I understand it though. I was hoping this could be done in a xml configuration file, without adding code. Is that not possible?

Comment: It can be done like you said, but did you change something in the "application.properties" file? you've got there a "server.servlet.session.timeout" value. P.S. this value is in Seconds. Also you did not mention what you wanted, if you want to deactivate the timeout you can set it to zero.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that this values is in seconds

```
<session-config>
         <session-timeout>1</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

And this value will be rounded to the minutes.

If server does not receive any requests from e.g you GUI, It will wait at least 1 min and then expire session.